# What is the wrap-around effect?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

What is the wrap-around effect?

Comment: Depends on the context.  Are we discussing the DFT?  Or are we discussing aliasing in the sampling process?  Or are we discussing twos-complement integers of a finite word size?  Or are we discussing efficiently implementing a delay line in memory.  Or are we discussing the modulo operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap around happens when the value of a quantity moves outside the "main range" of values and is mapped back onto that range (either by explicit calculation, by a certain process, by accident, or by physical reality).

## Example:

Let's multiply two complex numbers

$$e^{\jmath\pi} \cdot e^{\jmath 1.5\pi} = e^{\jmath 2.5\pi}$$

It looks like the angle of the result should be $2.5\pi$, but if you do the actual multiplication and determine the angle of the result it will be $0.5\pi$. The angle is periodic with $2\pi$ and an angle of $2.5\pi$ "wraps around" to $0.5\pi$

Other examples are the overflow behavior of two's complement fixed point math or aliasing.